# List incoming edges in Neo4j from Java slow

Tags: neo4j

I have a large graph (20M+ nodes) stored in a Neo4J database. 
From a Java program, I need to retrieve the sets of incoming edges of several nodes and compute their intersection.
The indegree of  some nodes in my graph is quite high (>300,000).

I tried the following:

on a node with 390,241 incoming edges and it took 10 seconds to complete.
However, if I store the node relations in a PostgreSQL database I can retrieve all incoming relations of this node in less than 1 second.
The problem is that I have to repeat this operation for several (possibly, high-indegree) nodes, which takes a lot of time. I thought that after warmup the Neo4j database would react faster, but it is not the case.

```
for ( Relationship r : source.getRelationships(Direction.INCOMING, DynamicRelationshipType.withName("Link")) ) 
{
    Node other = r.getOtherNode(source);
    set.add(other);
}
```

I don't really want to replicate my graph in PostgreSQL only for this operation, so I would need some hints (if any) to speed up Neo4j.

My computer has 32G of RAM, the Java heap space for my program is 20G. 
All the other settings are as per default values.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Which version of Neo4j? instead of `r.getOtherNode(source)` you might try `r.getStartNode()` (since your looking at INCOMING). But I guess this will not make a big improvement. What do you do later on with the result nodes? How many properties do you store on these?

Comment: What kind of disk do you have? Any chance to share your full program? Which Neo4j version are you using?

Comment: Hi Stefan, thanks for your answer, I use Neo4j 2.2.1. 
Indeed, by using getStartNode()  it is slightly faster, but that did not solve my problem. 
My nodes have just 3 properties: a numeric identifier, and two strings (512 chars max). 
I have to store the result nodes in a set and retrieve similar sets for other nodes and compute an intersection.

Comment: On a warm store that should be almost instant. I think you should adapt your memory mapping settings, dbms.pagecache.memory=Xg  to be the sum of nodestore + relstore + some of the property-store. I don't think you need 20G heap, 8-12 or so should be enough

Comment: Hi Michael, I have a SSD hdd 500GB. 
I'll try what you're suggesting for the memory mapping settings.
Just to make sure I understand, the size of the relstore   is the size of the file neostore.relationshipstore.db?

Comment: Yes. And try to run it twice, to see how it performs the second time around.

Comment: Oh and make sure to size the HashSet upfront, to e.g. 500k

Comment: Michael, I tried what you suggested and indeed my program runs faster. I still have some issues, but I'm confident they do not come from Neo4j. So, thanks a lot for your comments and suggestions.